# Problemas al enviar mensaje por formulario con ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, web, phpmailer

Hola a todos espero puedan ayudarme, lo que sucede es que cree un formulario en un sitio para que envié información por correo electrónico, lo que estoy usando es AJAX y PHP con la librería PHPMailer pero no envía la información, de lo que estoy seguro es que el archivo PHP funciona bien mi problema es con AJAX ya que cuando pongo este método a prueba, no manda la información incluso cuando todos los campos tienen datos.

```
<form method="POST" class="contactForm">
                        <input type="text" class="costumerData" id="costumerName" name="costumerInfoName" placeholder="Juan Diaz" required>
                        <div class="alert alert-name">
                            <div class="alertContainer">
                                <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
                                <p class="alertInfo">Este Campo es Obligatorio</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <input type="email" class="costumerData" id="costumerEmail" name="costumerInfoEmail" placeholder="juandiaz@gmail.com" required>
                        <div class="alert alert-email">
                            <div class="alertContainer">
                                <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
                                <p class="alertInfo">Correo Electrónico no Valido</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <textarea class="costumerData" id="costumerMessage" name="costumerInfoMessage" placeholder="Escriba su Mensaje" required></textarea>
                        <button type="submit"><i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i>  Enviar Mensaje</button>
                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                            <div class="alertContainer">
                            <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
                            <p class="alertInfo">Su mensaje fue enviado satisfactoriamente.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="alert alert-error">
                            <div class="alertContainer">
                            <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                            <p class="alertInfo">Su mensaje no se pudo enviar.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="alert alert-warning">
                            <div class="alertContainer">
                                <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
                                <p class="alertInfo">Todos los campos son Obligatorios</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Este es mi código JS:

Este código ya lo he puesto de diferentes maneras pero no sucede nada, esta es la ultima forma en la que lo escribí.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var costumerName = $('#costumerName').val();
var costumerEmail = $('#costumerEmail').val();
var costumerMessage = $('#costumerMessage').val();
var regex = /[\w-\.]{2,}@([\w-]{2,}\.)*([\w-]{2,}\.)[\w-]{2,4}/;

$('button').click(function() {
    if(costumerName.val == "" || costumerName.length >= 25){
        $('alert-name').fadeIn();
        $('.alert-name').fadeOut(5000);
        return false;
    }else{
        if(costumerEmail.val == "" || costumerEmail.length > 100 || !regex.test(costumerEmail)){
            $('.alert-email').fadeIn();
            $('.alert-email').fadeOut(5000);
            return false;
        }else{
            if(costumerName.val == "" && costumerEmail.val == "" && costumerMessage.val == ""){
                $('.alert-warning').fadeIn();
                $('.alert-warning').fadeOut(5000);
                return false;
            }else{
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "../php/enviar-prueba.php",
                    data: $('.contactForm').serialize(),
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    success: function (response) {
                        if(response == "ok"){
                            console.log('success');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(response) {
                        if(response == "no"){
                            console.log('Error!');
                        }
                    }

                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

También pongo mi código de PHP por cualquier cosa:

```
?php

function validarCampo($campo) {
    $campo = trim($campo);
    $campo = stripcslashes($campo);
    $campo = htmlspecialchars($campo);

    return $campo;
}

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

header('Content-Type: application/json');

if (isset($_POST['costumerInfoName']) && !empty($_POST['costumerInfoName']) &&
    isset($_POST['costumerInfoEmail']) && !empty($_POST['costumerInfoEmail']) && filter_var($_POST['costumerInfoEmail'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) &&
    isset($_POST['costumerInfoMessage']) && !empty($_POST['costumerInfoMessage'])) {

        $nameInfo = validarCampo($_POST['costumerInfoName']);
        $emailInfo = validarCampo($_POST['costumerInfoEmail']);
        $messageInfo = validarCampo($_POST['costumerInfoMessage']);
        $cuerpo_mensaje ='<head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head>';
        $cuerpo_mensaje .= '<html lang="es"><body>';
        $cuerpo_mensaje .= '<table style="width:100%;">';
        $cuerpo_mensaje .= '<thead style="background-color:#1f93cd;color:#ffffff;font-size:40px;"><tr>';
        $cuerpo_mensaje .= '<th style="text-align:center;width:100%;font-weight:normal;">Datos de Cliente</th>';
        $cuerpo_mensaje .= '</tr></thead>';
        $cuerpo_mensaje .= '<tr style="font-size:20px;"><td style="font-weight:bold;width:50%;">Nombre de Cliente</td><td style="width:50%;">'.$nameInfo.'</td></tr>';
        $cuerpo_mensaje .= '<tr style="background-color:#eaeaea;font-size:20px"><td style="font-weight:bold;width:50%;">Correo Electrónico</td><td style="width:50%;">'.$emailInfo.'</td></tr>';
        $cuerpo_mensaje .= '<tr><td style="font-weight:bold;text-align:center; font-size:20px;">Mensaje de Cliente:</td></tr>';
        $cuerpo_mensaje .= '<tr style="font-size:20px;"><td>'.$messageInfo.'</td></tr>';
        $cuerpo_mensaje .= '</table>';
        $cuerpo_mensaje .= '</body></html>';

        require 'PHPMailer/Exception.php';
        require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
        require 'PHPMailer/SMTP.php';

        // Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

        try {
            //Server settings
            $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                      // Enable verbose debug output
            $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
            $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
            $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
            $mail->Username   = 'micorreo@gmail.com';                     // SMTP username
            $mail->Password   = '';                               // SMTP password
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
            $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above

             //Recipients
            $mail->setFrom($emailInfo, $nameInfo);
            $mail->addAddress('edgarseguraflores@gmail.com');     // Add a recipient

            // Content
            $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
            $mail->Subject = 'mensaje enviado desde la pagina';
            $mail->Body    = $cuerpo_mensaje;
            $mail->send();
            echo json_encode('ok');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            //echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
            echo json_encode('no');
        }
}
```

?>

Comment: Por cierto, comprueba de que se este haciendo la petición ajax, si no se esta haciendo la petición ajax, sospecho que puede que tu regex este mal, por que lo demas parece estar bien.

Answer (score 0):

Puede que tengas un problema usando json_encode a la hora de enviar una respuesta del lado de PHP, lo que estas metiendo en el json creo que no tiene formato valido como json si no estoy mal, me explico, cuando tu pones:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Haces automaticamente que php restrinja la información que debe devolver a un formato json, pero claro, si usas json_encode de esta manera:

```
echo json_encode('ok');
```

Lo mas probable es que ocurra una excepción del lado del servidor, ya que json_encode esta pensado para usarse con arrays, algo como esto:

```
echo json_encode(['ok']);
```

o esto:

```
echo json_encode(["state" => ok]);
```

tambien debes tener cuidado con el puerto, y otra cosa que debes tener en cuenta es que si quieres enviar un correo a una dirección de gmail tienes que habilitar algo especial en tu gmail para hacerlo, o por lo menos para hacerlo desde

```
localhost
```

en caso de que intentes esto desde un servidor en la web autenticado no es necesario (algo diferente autenticado y seguro, por ejemplo una pagina web ya subida a un servidor).

Ahora mismo no recuerdo exactamente donde se habilita esa opción en gmail para hacer pruebas, pero es completamente necesario para `localhost` de lo contrario siempre va a fallar tu petición para enviar un correo (google rechazara estos correos pensando que es spam inseguro).

Según se, el puerto que usa **Hotmail** para conexion segura es **587**, pero el que usa gmail **no es ese** es `465`.

Con esta información, deberas primero habilitar los origines inseguros desde gmail y tambien cambiar el puerto a 465, en caso de que estes usando localhost o un servidor local cualquiera.

Creo que ya encontre el error, es muy estupido no haberme dado cuenta antes xd, observa atentamente lo siguiente:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var costumerName = $('#costumerName').val();
    var costumerEmail = $('#costumerEmail').val();
    var costumerMessage = $('#costumerMessage').val();
    var regex = /[\w-\.]{2,}@([\w-]{2,}\.)*([\w-]{2,}\.)[\w-]{2,4}/;

    $('button').click(function() {

    }

}
```

vez algo extraño?, yo sí, lo que pasa es que el valor de los campos no esta siendo actualizado cuando das click al boton:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    //Aquí deben ser actualizados los campos
}
```

el resultado es que de inicios los value de los inputs estan vacios, y como nunca los actualizas siempre quedan vacios, lo ideal sería que dentro del clik hicieras esto:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    costumerName = $('#costumerName').val();
    costumerEmail = $('#costumerEmail').val();
    costumerMessage = $('#costumerMessage').val();

    y en vez de hacer esto:
    if(costumerName.val == "" || costumerName.length >= 25){

    }

    //Hacer esto
    if(costumerName == "" || costumerName.length >= 25){

    }

    /*
      Deberas hacer estos arreglos en donde estes usando la 
      propiedad val de alguno de tus inputs, ya que realmente
      la propiedad val ya la extrajiste anteriormente.
    /*
}
```

Esto le da sentido al porque del lado del servidor aparentemente ajax no estaba funcionando, es decir, cuando tu pusiste esta condición:

```
if (isset($_POST['costumerInfoName']) && !empty($_POST['costumerInfoName']) &&
    isset($_POST['costumerInfoEmail']) && !empty($_POST['costumerInfoEmail']) && filter_var($_POST['costumerInfoEmail'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) &&
    isset($_POST['costumerInfoMessage']) && !empty($_POST['costumerInfoMessage'])) {

}
```

no le añadiste un else, al final, es decir no le dijiste que si no se cumplia eso, debia hacerse algo, y tu no estas retornando nada en caso de que la condición no se cumpla por lo tanto `ajax` no te devolvia nada puesto que el response type debe ser en formato json, entonces deberias agregarle un else y retornar algo tambien:

```
if (isset($_POST['costumerInfoName']) && !empty($_POST['costumerInfoName']) &&
    isset($_POST['costumerInfoEmail']) && !empty($_POST['costumerInfoEmail']) && filter_var($_POST['costumerInfoEmail'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) &&
    isset($_POST['costumerInfoMessage']) && !empty($_POST['costumerInfoMessage'])) {

   //Código

}else{
   echo json_encode(["state" => "no"]);
}
```

Comment: Revise todo y sigue igual

Comment: Pero se ejecuta tu petición ajax?, ahora mismo te debería estar retornando ya sea 'ok' o 'no'.

Comment: No me retorna nada de hecho la página se recarga y nada más

Comment: Si estas usando ajax por que se recargaria xd? debe ser algo en el código... pero de todas maneras eso significa que lo mas probable es que nisiquiera se este llegando a la parte donde ejecutas ajax, ya que si no, verias por consola algo que te devolviese ajax. ya sea ok o no en formato json. debes tener cuidado con que no estes usando un boton de submit para enviar los datos a ajax porque si tu metodo es post en el form y no previenes que se recargue la pagina al clikear en el boton submit, no sabras por consola si hubo o no un error y los datos serían enviados normalmente y no por ajax.

Comment: Por ahora que tal si tratas de no hacer ninguna validación y poner tu código de ajax en esa función para que se ejecute directamente?, así puedes verificar si hay o no un problema con la petición, yo creo que es la regex que seguro esta dando problemas.

Comment: No ocurre nada, ya quite la validación y sigue sin mandar el correo solo deje el bloque de ajax y cambie el boton de tipo submit a solo boton y nada.

Comment: Y si enrealidad no estas entrando al if dentro de php...? tambien puede ser. por que de otra forma esto es algo muy extraño... pareciera incluso como si ajax no te estuviese funcionando... lo cual es sumamente extraño...

Comment: posdata, muy pero muy muy raras vecez en linux por ejemplo los navegadores choquean y deja de actualizarse esa pagina así tu la recargues sea como sea, a mi me paso una vez y estuve horas viendo como no me queria ejecutar los cambios, puede que te pase esto... yo lo solucione cerrando la pestaña completamente reniciando el servidor y volviendo a abrirla.

Comment: Checa de nuevo mi respuesta, le agregue algo mas, puede que ahora si te sirva :3

Comment: Ya hice los cambios que me sugeriste y sigue igual